# Is hitting a foam ball against a wall in training detrimental to my tennis?

Tags: tennis, training

I have recently begun hitting a foam ball against the wall to improve my volleys, since I have been playing more doubles lately. I think the benefits are reduced noise and it is not so hard on my arm joints, since it is not as heavy as a regular ball. It is a lot easier to keep the volleys going too, since it's more forgiving.

I do overheads, serves and volleys against a racketball court wall.  I think it's a great cardio exercise, and I have seem some improvements on my volleys; I am more aggressive at the net now.

Are there any drawbacks to hitting with the foam ball, if I still hit with the regular balls from time to time?

Answer (score 2):

The central risk is getting used to incorrect technique. Since foam balls are significantly lighter than tennis balls, hitting them offers less feedback. Consequently many players begin swinging and/or using their wrists instead of leaning in. In the meantime, the light balls do not punish these mistakes and moreover obscure bad timing.

Answer (score 0):

In and of itself, it's probably not detrimental, but it also probably isn't helping you very much beyond maybe half an hour a day.

Practice like you play. That means, practice by recreating the same conditions you will play in, to the greatest extent possible.